# Https Post Request Response

Tags: ios, swift3

```
private func makeLoginRestCall(email:String, password:String){
guard let url = URL(string: "http://-----------/PassengerLogin.php") else {
        return
    }
    var request = URLRequest(url:url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let emailString : String = "email="
    let parameters = emailString + email+",password=" + password
    request.httpBody = parameters.data(using: .utf8)
    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with:request) {
        (data,response,error) in
        if let response = response {
            print(response)
        }else{
            print("No response")
        }
        if let data = data {
            do{
                let json  = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary
                print(json ?? "No data found")
            }catch{
                print(error)
            }
        }else {
            print("No data found")
        }
    }.resume()}
```

When I send this request from simulator I always get invalid email response.
But When I send this request from postman I get all user details .
Please help new here
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Change , to & in parameters

Comment: are you sure, server expecting parameters as a string? you may need to put the parameters into a dictionary and send it.

Comment: Thank solve my problem@vp2698